# Size of preview image in Lyx?

Tags: graphics, lyx

When I insert an image into Lyx, there is an option to control the size of the image in the compiled PDF. However, the size of the preview is not affected by this setting. This means that I sometimes end up with huge preview images, that don't even fit in the screen.

Is there a way to control the size of preview images in Lyx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, but it's a bit primitive, especially when it comes to vector graphics.
Same dialog where you set the output size: there are three tabs - Graphics, Clipping, LaTeX and LyX options. In the third tab, there's the option "Scale on screen". Set it to some lower value.